# Java WatchService unexpectedly stops working

Tags: java, spring, java-8, watchservice

I have a recursive watch service that I'm using to monitor directories while the application is running. For an unknown reason, the watchservice appears stop working after about a day. At that point I can add a new file to a monitored directory and get no log statements and my observers are not notified.

I thought Spring might be destroying the bean, so I added a log statement to the @pre-destroy section of the class, but that log statement doesn't show up after the watchservice stops working, so it seems that bean still exists, it's just not functioning as expected. The class is as follows

```
import com.sun.nio.file.SensitivityWatchEventModifier;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;

@Service
public class DirectoryMonitor {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DirectoryMonitor.class);
private WatchService watcher;
private ExecutorService executor;
private List<DirectoryMonitorObserver> observerList = new ArrayList<>();
private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys = new HashMap<>();

public void addObserver(DirectoryMonitorObserver observer){
    observerList.add(observer);
}

private void notifyObservers(){
    observerList.forEach(DirectoryMonitorObserver::directoryModified);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws IOException {
    watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanup() {
    try {
        logger.info("Stopping directory monitor");
        watcher.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error closing watcher service", e);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void startRecursiveWatcher(String pathToMonitor) {
    logger.info("Starting Recursive Watcher");

    Consumer<Path> register = p -> {
        if (!p.toFile().exists() || !p.toFile().isDirectory())
            throw new RuntimeException("folder " + p + " does not exist or is not a directory");

        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(p, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    logger.info("registering " + dir + " in watcher service");
                    WatchKey watchKey = dir.register(watcher, new WatchEvent.Kind[]{ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE}, SensitivityWatchEventModifier.HIGH);
                    keys.put(watchKey, dir);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error registering path " + p);
        }
    };

    register.accept(Paths.get(pathToMonitor));

    executor.submit(() -> {
        while (true) {
            final WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.error(ex.toString());
                continue;
            }

            final Path dir = keys.get(key);

            key.pollEvents().stream()
                    .map(e -> ((WatchEvent<Path>) e).context())
                    .forEach(p -> {
                        final Path absPath = dir.resolve(p);
                        if (absPath.toFile().isDirectory()) {
                            register.accept(absPath);
                        } else {
                            final File f = absPath.toFile();
                            logger.info("Detected new file " + f.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                    });

            notifyObservers();
            key.reset();
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is where I'm creating the monitor bean..

```
@Component
public class MovieInfoFacade {
    @Value("${media.path}")
    private String mediaPath;
    private MovieInfoControl movieInfoControl;
    private DirectoryMonitor directoryMonitor;
    private FileListProvider fileListProvider;

@Autowired
public MovieInfoFacade(MovieInfoControl movieInfoControl, DirectoryMonitor directoryMonitor, FileListProvider fileListProvider){
    this.movieInfoControl = movieInfoControl;
    this.directoryMonitor = directoryMonitor;
    this.fileListProvider = fileListProvider;
}

@PostConstruct
public void startDirectoryMonitor(){
    if(!mediaPath.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
        directoryMonitor.addObserver(fileListProvider);
        directoryMonitor.startRecursiveWatcher(mediaPath);
    }
}

public int loadMovieListLength(String directoryPath){
    return fileListProvider.listFiles(directoryPath).length;
}

public List<MovieInfo> loadMovieList(MovieSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    List<File> files = Arrays.asList(fileListProvider.listFiles(searchCriteria.getPath()));

    return files.parallelStream()
            .sorted()
            .skip(searchCriteria.getPage() * searchCriteria.getItemsPerPage())
            .limit(searchCriteria.getItemsPerPage())
            .map(file -> movieInfoControl.loadMovieInfoFromCache(file.getAbsolutePath()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public MovieInfo loadSingleMovie(String filePath) {
    return movieInfoControl.loadMovieInfoFromCache(filePath);
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly happens? How do you know it stops? Do you see any events in the event-handlar of the os?

Comment: I added more details to the question. Essentially I get no log output and my observers are not notified as they normally are.

Comment: How do you know the program actually stopped then? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the error was in my exception handling. After removing the throw statements (and replacing them with logs) I have not had any issues.